# Is there any bloodstream chemical composition software simulator?

Tags: pharmacology, hematology, software

Let's say I'd like to know how certain substance affects bloodstream levels of certain drug during a period of time. Is there any simulation software available publicly to run such kind of simulation?

Comment: Pretty much any spreadsheet can be used for this, you just need the requisite data (and to know how to program equations). Can you be more specific about the drugs and the context in which you're needing the data?

Comment: @Jiminy Cricket it's necessary to know what to drink/eat in order to increase suction rate  (into bloodstream) of a certain drug. Where to get data for a spreadsheet?

Comment: @Jiminy Cricket or some substance instead of a drug.

Comment: This is all very vague at present, also the question you ask doesn't seem to be the question you need an answer to. Please take our [tour] and read up in the [help], paying particular attention to the [ask] section - then [edit] your question to ask what you intend and include the details which are missing such as your prior researches and the substances in question.

Comment: Usually you give someone (or a rodent) the drug, and take measurements of their blood regularly after that. How you actually detect the drug in the blood depends on the drug.

Comment: In addition, the drug taken isn't the active one sometimes, it's the breakdown products that are the active ones. You'd need to be specific about the substances in question.

Comment: @Jiminy Cricket two things: benzimidazole type of substances and caffeine.

Comment: Could you please do as suggested - take our [tour] and read the [ask] section of the [help] then [edit] your question into shape. Comments don't last and the question itself should contain all the requisite information necessary to answer.

Comment: Welcome to the site Ya Y! I would love to see this question be edited to add some of your clarifying details that you've brought up in the comments.